# Dependency failure when running cordova run android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error when building my project.

> Dependency failing:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:15.0.2 ->
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@[15.0.2], but
>   play-services-measurement-base version was 15.0.4.

Following is my application and project level build.gradle files.

*root build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // fabric dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
}
```

*app build.gradle*

```
 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.5.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.5"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```